# How do I fix the error "Result of operator '>=' is unused"

Tags: swift

I have the error mentioned above for the two lines that are commented below, using an equals sign works, but when I use the '>=' sign... The error continues to show up. It's not an error with my pause function, I've tested it with the equals sign, so could you please tell me what to fix. Thanks!

```
func addScore(playerWhoWon : SKSpriteNode){

    ball.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    if playerWhoWon == main {
        score[0] >= 10 // THAT"S WHERE I GET MY ERROR
        pauseGame()
        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 10, dy: 10))
    }
    else if playerWhoWon == enemy {
        score[1] >= 10 // SECOND LINE WHERE I GET MY ERROR
        pauseGame()
        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -10, dy: -10))
    }

    topLbl.text = "\(score[1])"
    btmLbl.text = "\(score[0])"
}
```

Comment: What do you expect that `score[0] >= 1` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517115/how-do-i-pause-game-after-score-reaches-10), what you should be doing is creating an `if` statement:

```
if score[0] >= 10 {
    pauseGame()
}
```

I also strongly urge you to spend lots of time reading the [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) book from Apple.

Answer (score 2):

Using an equal sign (`=`) means *assignment*. When you say: `score[0] = 10` it means that you assign `10` to the first element of the array `score`. This is why it works.

Using greater than or equals sign (`>=`) means *comparison*, so it returns a boolean value as the result of the comparison. And you are not doing anything with that result, so this is why you are getting the warning.

When you use something that returns a result and you don't want to use that result, you can use:

```
_ = score[0] >= 10
```

You shouldn't do this in your case for sure, and as mentioned by @rmaddy, you should be using an `if` statement to fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks a-lot bro still a relative beginner in this swift stuff, so every bit helps :)